# Which parameters could be used to determine that two sentient beings are from differente species?

Tags: biology, xenobiology

Let's say that there is an alien species of sentient beings, called Alpha.
They are suped-advanced in bio-engineering (like DNA manipulation, medicine, etc...).

At one point of their history, their society breaks into two major groups:

- one, called **Beta**, that decides to apply bio-engineering on themselves to create hybrids, super-specimens, monstruosities and such
- the other one, called **Delta**, that believes in the purity of their species and won't allow the application of those technologies on themselves.

At which point one could say that Beta and Delta (Alfa) have become two different species? Which parameters could be used to determine that Beta has become a different species from Delta (Alfa)?

Comment: This seems highly relevant: https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_41

Comment: From the moment the Beta decided to bioengineer themselves into another species -in fact, more than one. When a species assumes the genetic traits of another species, and said integrations is full and irreversible, then you have a whole new species,

Comment: Welcome to WorldBuilding! A little tip about markdown: to get a markdown list you need to have one empty line before the first one that starts with a "-" or number. To get a paragraph you need to hit Enter twice. For soft linebreaks you need two spaces at the end of a line before hitting Enter once, but most people prefer paragraphs, so I removed that not-quite linebreak. There is a little box with markdown tips above the box where you type that might help you. If you have a moment please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to learn more about the site. Have fun!

Comment: Hello *R. Satriani*, and welcome to Worldbuilding.  This looks like a question that is somewhat opinion based.  Perhaps you could edit to include more criteria as to what would make one answer better than another.  Please take the [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about the site.   Have a nice day!

Comment: Morphology (anatomy) and genetics are the most common way of determining species, if you can show they are morphologically distinct and have not shared genetic material for a significant amount of time, you can argue they are different species.

Comment: this strongly depends on the criteria they use to define a species.

Comment: So, I'll try to put together Valerio and John answers:
let's say that every Beta decided to have green skin and horns, as distinctive traits. At this point one could say that Beta and Delta (Alfa) have become two different species, as long as they don't interbreed anymore?

Comment: This is just a question about the meaning of the word “species”, and so has no undeniably right answer. Define precisely what _you_ mean by that word, and your question will then answer itself. But others may be using a different definition and so they won’t agree with you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### TL;DR: Different species can't interbreed. Your Betas are probably multiple species themselves

---

#### The term "species"

If you mean the classical term of biology "species". The term species is referring to a group of animals similar enough to one another to interbreed. This is not as clear as you might think.

When a population splits they can have different selective pressures and develop slightly different traits. But neighboring populations tend to still be able to interbreed while more distant populations might not be able to.

The following image shows this. The lines between the different populations show neighboring populations. Due to the ongoing divergence over time as the populations travel around the barrier they might become so different that the final specimens of both groups can no longer interbreed, although you can form a path of populations to them only with closely related ones.

This concept is called **ring species**.

[image: ring species]

#### Back to your populations

Since you mention the beta changing their own genes they probably become different species themselves as many differently modified specimen might still be able to reproduce with some, but won't be able to interbreed with all of the other betas. Some might modified so much that they can only interbreed with other who were modified exactly like them and thus being a singular species.

**And thus not only would the Beta be different from the Delta, but they would also be a multi-species community.**

Comment: the geographical separation is a very interesting concept. What biological traits could cause the two populations to not be able to interbreed anymore?

Comment: @R.Satriani: It's not that much specific traits that inhibit interbreeding, but more generally being too different. Let's say you have a huge lake with one side being more like a mountain range and the other side being flatlands. If the populations are not moving that much locally they can become better adapted to their side of the lake and once both paths meet at the end of the lake they have become too different despite being still able to interbreed with the intermediate populations.

Comment: Different species can interbreed (some of them), but their offsrpings are fertile : horse + donkey = mule.

Comment: @Hawker65 i think you meant infertile

Comment: @R.Satriani Google "ring species" and you'll find plenty of info on the concept

Comment: @ArtificialSoul It would be worth using the title/phrase "ring species" in your answer so people can do further research on it if they are interested.

Comment: Yep, I meant infertile, my bad.

Comment: @TimB You are absolutely correct. It is the term i find that picture from after all. I just forgot to put it into my answer. Thanks!